# push is behaving weird

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement push notification in Android app & it's working fine however have issue in 1 case.

Code I followed is as below.

```
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

    remoteMessage.notification?.let {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.title}")
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: ${it.body}")
        if ((it.body ?: "").isNotEmpty()) {
            sendNotification(it.title ?: getString(R.string.app_name), it.body ?: "", 602) // for now for test I am sending fix project id
        }
    }
}

private fun sendNotification(messageTitle : String, messageBody: String, projectId : Int) {

    Log.d("fapa", "sendNotification")

    val resultData = ProjectDetailsResponseModelModified.ResultBean.Projects()
    resultData.projectId = projectId
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = gson.toJson(resultData)

    val intentPD = Intent(this, ProjectDetailsActivity::class.java)
    intentPD.putExtra(AppConstants.PROJECT, json)
    intentPD.putExtra(AppConstants.strDonationTypeID,AppConstants.DonationFromProjectOrCampaigns)

    val intentSplash = Intent(this, SplashActivity::class.java)


    // intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    val num = System.currentTimeMillis().toInt()

    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num /* Request code */, intentSplash,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

    if (projectId >= 1) {
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, num /* Request code */, intentPD,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }

    val channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id)
    val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
        .setContentTitle(messageTitle)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_ic)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

    val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

    // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val channel = NotificationChannel(channelId,
            "Channel human readable title",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    notificationManager.notify(num /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build())
}
```

### Case 1 : Working fine

Now I run app and send push. When I click on push notification, it take me to project details.

### Case 2 : Working fine but when click back, close app.

Now open is still open and I send push but didn't click. Now I kill app and click on push notification. It take me to project details.

In this case, I was expecting to open Home activity and then go to details because app was not open.

### Case 3 : Not working fine.

Now I kill app and send push. Push comes & when click it opens Splash and not take me to project details.

In this case, I was expecting to open Home activity and then go to details.

What I am missing here OR how to get this achieved in Android Kotlin?

In iOS, we have option to write code when click on the push so we can check stack and go to splash/home & then go to details but here it didn't seem to have it.

---

### Edit 1

I tried to get extras in Splash with below code

```
if (intent.extras != null) {
    Log.d("fapa", "extrass==inside")
    val intent2 = intent.extras
    Log.d("fapa", "extrass==inside=0001==")
    Log.d("fapa", "extrass==inside=0001==" + intent2)
    if (intent2 != null) {
        Log.d(
            "fapa",
            "extrass==inside=0002==" + intent2!!.getString(AppConstants.PROJECT)
        )
```

but here I get something else as below.

```
Bundle[{google.delivered_priority=high, google.sent_time=1710670285220, google.ttl=2419200, google.original_priority=high, google.product_id=133506909, from=635413371669, google.message_id=0:1710670285232731%e9275269e9275269, gcm.n.analytics_data=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=348], collapse_key=com.sdsdsdsd}]
```

This don't have data of project details which I get in push.